# No differences among aggregate standard deviations in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, statistics

In a MySQL database I have a view (view_one) that contains a number of vegetation indices for several agricultural fields. The fields are further devided into plots, transects and points.

Here's the basic table design:

measure_id | field_id | plot_id | transect | point | vegetation_index_1 | .... |

I create a second view for the average values of the vegetation indices per plot and their respective standard deviation.

`create view plot_avgs (measure_id, field_id, plot_id, avg_VI1, stddev_VI1, ... 
as select measure_id, field_id, plot_id, avg(VI1), stddev_samp(VI1), ... 
from view_one group by measure_id, field_id, plot_id;`

What I want is the standard deviation of the plot, thus of the sample (`stddev_samp()`).

What MySQL gives me, however, is the stddev of the population, regardless the use of `stddev(plot_avg)`, `std(plot_avg)`, `stddev_pop(plot_avg)` or `stddev_samp(plot_avg)`.

I'm suspecting that it has something to do with the group by aggregation I'm using.

Who can help me out? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved things myself:

if I use the very same `as select ... from ...` statement that I had intended to create the view with and either just run the query or use it to create a table, I do get the desired standard deviation of the sample (plot). As described in the question, this does not happen when creating the view.

So what I will do is use a permanent table instead of the view and have it updated by a trigger any time I'm inserting new data into the raw data table.